# Is conversion between images and a text PDF possible

Tags: pdf, image-manipulation

I have a scanned book as *images* compressed into a **PDF** file and I want to *keep the book as is*, but would like to extract the text from the images, so that it would be possible to select/copy it.

Is there a way to to this under Linux?

Comment: check out the discussion at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301318/how-to-ocr-a-pdf-file-and-get-the-text-stored-within-the-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the text with optical character recognition program (OCR). This should give you an overview what is available under linux https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR .