# How to OCR a PDF file and get the text stored within the PDF?

Tags: command-line, pdf, ocr

First, apologies if this has been asked before - I searched for a while through the existing posts, but could not find support.

I am interested in a solution for Fedora to OCR a multipage non-searchable PDF and to turn this PDF into a new PDF file that contains the text layer on top of the image. On Mac OSX or Windows we could use Adobe Acrobat, but is there a solution on Linux, specifically on Fedora?

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20190807064639/https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/pdf-ocr-linux/) seems to describe a solution - but unfortunately I am already lost when retrieving exact-image.

Comment: There is a problem with the nice  pdfocr script that the page you are linking to recommends: it relies upon pdftk which is essentially deprecated (for two reasons, its dependence on libgcj and on iText5+). So a different solution is needed anyway...

Answer (score 116, accepted):

[`ocrmypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/ocrmypdf/) does a good job and can be used like this:

```
ocrmypdf in.pdf out.pdf
```

To install:

```
pip install ocrmypdf
```

or

```
sudo apt install ocrmypdf     # ubuntu
sudo dnf -y install ocrmypdf  # fedora
```

Comment: Used `ocrmypdf` on Fedora 30 (via `dnf install`) - worked like a charm.

Comment: very good, thanks. Unlike the other ocr proposed in this thread, this ocr gives an output only _slighlty bigger_ than the original (image pdf). It would even better if it could give an output _smaller_ (only text): it is possible?

Comment: @Duns if you will do that the resulting text layout will have a lot of errors, so you cannot using this tool, there is no way to have a decent looking OCRed without the original layout output, another better dimension and better looking solution would be Adobe Clearscan  or alternative to clearscan 
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/are-there-other-products-than-adobes-that-support-clearscan-or-similiar

Comment: @MartinThoma I would leave it there maybe there are older versions that still have the app and maybe pypdfocr  will be cotinued again at some point

Comment: OCRmyPDF worked like a dream for me too.  It’s based on Tesseract under the hood, so (among other things) handles [many languages](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html) well: I just used it for a document in a mixture of English and Georgian (ქართული ენა) and got near-perfect results.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04:  When creating an ocr pdf, `ocrmypdf` states that `jbig2enc` is not installed and is needed for compressing and higher quality PDF files.  `jbig2enc` must be built from source, but it has dependencies of `libtool` [that contains both `libtoolize` and `glibtoolize`] to be installed with `sudo apt install libtool`, and `libleptonica-dev` (which contains `Leptonica`):  `sudo apt install libleptonica-dev`.  Then, follow the instructions for git-cloning `jbig2enc` at `git clone https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc` and running `./autogen.sh` / `./config` / `make` / `sudo make install`

Answer (score 22):

After learning that [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) can now also produce searchable PDFs, I found the script sandwich: http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/

after installing dependencies (this might not be the complete list)

```
sudo dnf install svn ocaml unpaper tesseract
```

I followed the script's guide for compiling from source

> Compile from sources
>
> pdfsandwich is open source software (license: GPL). You can download the sources either as .tar.bz2 package from the download area on the project website or check them out by subversion:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/pdfsandwich/code/trunk/src pdfsandwich
```

> If OCaml is installed on your system, you can compile and install as follows:

```
cd pdfsandwich
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and this now allows me to run

```
sandwich multipaged-non-searchable.pdf
```

resulting in a searchable PDF.

[Here](https://repology.org/project/pdfsandwich/versions) is a list of repositories (e.g., Debian Stable, AUR, Homebrew) containing pdfsandwich.

Comment: for a related, but separate question, building on this one, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306051/tesseract-is-it-possible-to-change-font-output-in-ocred-pdf

Comment: FWIW: pdfsandwich is also available in Ubuntu's apt package repository. Other distros might have it as well.

Comment: Just came across https://fedoramagazine.org/4-cool-new-projects-try-copr-october-2018/ showing a COPR package for fedora that packages pdfsandwich

Answer (score 8):

An easy tool available in Ubuntu is 'ocrfeeder' it allows the generation of PDFs with OCR text overlaid on the original documents. It makes use of Tesseract plus other OCR engines (not sure which) and provides for image rotation/'unpaper', etc, as well.

- http://live.gnome.org/OCRFeeder
- https://github.com/GNOME/ocrfeeder

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem so I wrote this over the weekend. Give it a shot; it works great! It is a simple wrapper around `tesseract`. It uses `pdftoppm` to convert a PDF into a bunch of TIFF files, then it uses `tesseract` to perform OCR (Optical Character Recognition) on them and produce a searchable PDF as output. All intermediate temporary files are automatically deleted when the script completes.

Source code: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF

### Instructions to install & use `pdf2searchablepdf`:

Tested on **Ubuntu 18.04** on 11 Nov 2019 and on **Ubuntu 20.04** Nov. 2020.

#### Install:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF.git
./PDF2SearchablePDF/install.sh

sudo apt update
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

#### Use:

```bash
# General:
pdf2searchablepdf [options] <input.pdf|dir_of_imgs> [lang]

# Make a PDF searchable:
pdf2searchablepdf mypdf.pdf

# Make an entire directory of images into a single searchable PDF:
pdf2searchablepdf directory_of_imgs
```

You'll now have a pdf called **mypdf_searchable.pdf**, which contains searchable text!

Done. It has no python dependencies, as it's currently written entirely in bash.

See `pdf2searchablepdf -h` for the help menu and more options and examples.

### References or Related Resources:

1. **PDF2SearchablePDF**: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/473843/how-to-turn-a-pdf-into-a-text-searchable-pdf/1187881#1187881
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16268/whats-the-best-simplest-ocr-solution
4. https://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf/1187844#1187844
5. **pdfsandwich**: Alternative software wrapper I just discovered, that is worth checking out too! http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/

Comment: Good utility. One thing you might do is add support for file names with spaces in them. Right now, that doesn't work (you get a usage message for `pdftoppm`). Just adding a few quotation marks in some of the commands should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll see when I can make the change and test it. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF/issues/6

Comment: @WilsonF, done! v0.4.0 just released to resolve this issue. https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF/releases

Comment: Excellent, thank you! (Trying to add an '@' tag in edit, but it isn't taking it.)

Comment: the problem is that the output file, for me (but in examples as well), is 100% bigger than original image pdf...

Comment: Yeah I've got an issue open for that. I'll fix it when able. It requires generating one high-res image for the OCR and another low-res image to be overlaid onto the OCRed text to regenerate a PDF after doing the OCR processing. See here: **Allow user to set the compression level of the output pdf** (https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF/issues/5)

Comment: @Duns, I still have to work out many of the details for a better long-term solution built in to my tool, but meanwhile, for some PDF compression options, see my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file/1303196#1303196.

Comment: Excellent utility. Faster and more stable than my brief experiments with ocrmypdf and pdfsandwich. This on Ubuntu 18.04 and only a couple of PDF scanned documents as images. My issues arose when having relatively high resolutions (300dpi).

Comment: @PatrickRefondini, are you saying your "issues arose" when using _my `pdf2searchablepdf` tool_ on resolutions >= 300 dpi, or when using one of the other tools you mentioned? With which tool did you have issues on high resolutions?

Comment: @GabrielStaples `pdf2searchablepdf` is fast and stable. I had issue with `ocrmypdf` and `pdfsandwich` when doing only a couple of tests with resolutions >= 300dpi.