# tesseract: is it possible to change font output in OCRed pdf?

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince, ocr, tesseract

Following up on [how to OCR a pdf file and get the text stored within pdf?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301318/how-to-ocr-a-pdf-file-and-get-the-text-stored-within-pdf/301319#301319) I have successfully produced OCRed pdf pages.

In Evince, however, the letters are not shown; by this I mean that I cannot see the characters, but I can select them, copy them and paste them elsewhere successfully. This does not seem to be a bug of Evince: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1364201

When initiating an OCR of a pdf page with pdfsandwich, tesseract produces a page that

> contains a font which doesn't have any
>   usable glyphs (they named it GlyphLessFont). It has only .notdef and
>   .null replacements (the squares). Evince uses the .notdef glyph if there
>   is no glyph for the character. The reason that Okular highlight the text
>   is because it does it in the image not as a regular text as evince does.

pdftotext recognises the characters.

Now, the question is: can tesseract be told to use a different font?

Comment: Does `pdftotext` recognize the characters?  (you may need to tweak character encoding)

Comment: Short answer, no. More discussion: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1769

Comment: @WeAreAllMonica `pdftotext` outputs recognizable characters now (at least as of 5.0alpha).

Answer (score 2):

You could customise this portion of the source code to your liking and change the font here. You will have to rebuild tesseract from source once you make the change.

[Tesseract Github Renderer.h](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/effa5741e6ef8bcb37d68250ca39c92fae85f6a9/api/renderer.h#L188)

Comment: thanks, but would you mind adding to your answer a bit more on how I would approach that? Sorry, am not a programmer, but can follow guidelines for rebuilding :) trying to understanding https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md does not even help me much to decide how to suggest such a change as a feature request